# Multiplication of "big Ints" in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm supposed to implement multiplication for big numbers in haskell. 
The big numbers are represented as lists, for example 123 is [1,2,3].
So far i've already implemented addition,

```
bigPlus [1,2,3] [4,5,6] 
> [5, 7, 9]
```

But right now, i'll have to do bigMultiply but i'm stuck as i have to implement it based on the skeleton code the assignment gives, i'm not allowed to change the skeleton code (i am however allowed to add nested "where")

```
bigMul :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]
bigMul l1 l2 = res
  where
    (_, res)   = foldRight f base args
    f x (z, p) = error "TBD"
    base       = error "TBD"
    args       = error "TBD"
```

where

```
foldRight::(b -> a -> a) -> a -> [b] -> a
foldRight = foldr
```

I've also written a method called digitMul such that

```
digitMul :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int]

digitMul 5 [1,1]
> [5,5] 

digitMul 0 [1,2,3]
> []
```

and digitMul is written with bigPlus. Could someone help me out with understanding and figuring out what I have? I'm completely lost with this one.

Other methods that might be useful are

```
replicate :: a -> Int -> [a]
-- | `replicate x n` returns a `[x,x,...,x]` containing `n` copies of `x`
--
-- >>> replicate 3 5
-- [3,3,3,3,3]

Zeros :: [Int] -> [Int] -> ([Int], [Int])
-- | `Zeros l1 l2` returns a pair (l1', l2') which are just the input lists,
--   padded with extra `0` on the left such that the lengths of `l1'` and `l2'`
--   are equal.
--
-- >>> Zeros [9,9] [1,0,0,2]
-- [0,0,9,9] [1,0,0,2]
--
-- >>> Zeros [1,0,0,2] [9,9]
-- [1,0,0,2] [0,0,9,9]

remZero :: [Int] -> [Int]
-- | `remZero ds` strips out all leading `0` from the left-side of `ds`.
--
-- >>> remZero [0,0,0,1,0,0,2]
-- [1,0,0,2]
--
```

Comment: Is carry working for addition and multiplication? `bigPlus [9,8,7] [2,4]`? BTW it would be much easier to represent 123 as `[3,2,1]` (i.e. least significant digits first).

Answer (score 6):

For real-world use, `Integer` is already the big-int type in Haskell, and in all honesty you could simply convert to `Integer`, multiply and convert back.

This sounds like homework, so I won’t give a complete answer, but here are some hints.

Since you can’t change the boilerplate, you need to write this as a `foldr` operation, which will run from back to front (that is, on the ones, then the tens, then the hundreds), produce a pair and pass it on to the next iteration of the fold.  You are free to define the first element of the pair, but the second needs to be the result, which is to say, a `BigInt` list.  So, you will be computing one step of the algorithm on each iteration and passing it on in the second component of the pair.  One method you could use would be to iterate over the digits of one of your multiplicands, multiplying the other number by that digit, multiplying again by the place you’re at (1, then 10, then 100), and adding to the accumulator.  This duplicates how I was taught to multiply by hand (maybe you learned with a grid, which would also be possible to do with Haskell).

If you do it this way, the other element you pass to the next iteration has to be the base, and it would need to be passed in the first component of the `res` pair, as that is the only other way for you to pass it on.  The `base` element should be the initial value passed to `foldr`, containing the ones place and a zero accumulator.  This function is `f`, where `x` is the current digit of the multiplicand, `z` is the number of zeroes to add and `p` the running sum so far.

That should be more than enough for you to write the program.